# Gomock unexposed interface as argument

Tags: go, testing, gomock

I'm using `gomock` (source mode) and wish to mock a piece of code that looks something like:

```
type foo interface {
  MethodA() int
}

type Boo interface {
  MethodB(f foo) string
}
```

where the unexported `foo` interface is used as an argument in `MethodB()`. After using mockgen, the mocked `MethodB()` looks like:

```
func (m &MockBoo) MethodB(f foo) string { ... }
```

which is erroneous because `foo` is unexported and can't be accessed.

Was wondering if theres a way around it (eg. for `foo` to be `Mockfoo` instead as the argument)?

PS. I tried gomock `reflect` mode as well but it had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

To test private types, declare your tests in the same package as the type. Doing so will allow you to access the private symbols.

---

##### Example

Test

```
package foo
import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/golang/mock/gomock"
)
func TestName(t *testing.T) {
    con := gomock.NewController(t)
    defer con.Finish()
    boo := NewMockBoo(con)
    var F foo
    boo.EXPECT().MethodB(F)
    if len(boo.MethodB(F)) > 0 {
        t.Fail()
    }
}
```

Generate mocks

```
$ mockgen -source=foo.go -package foo -destination foo_mock.go
```

foo.go

```
package foo


type foo interface {
  MethodA() int
}

type Boo interface {
  MethodB(f foo) string
}
```

Running the test:

```
$ go test  -v 
=== RUN   TestName
--- PASS: TestName (0.00s)
PASS
ok      foo 0.001s
```

Comment: Hi, the question is about generating mocks using gomocks with such private types. Gomock creates a different package

Comment: That is exactly what you want it not do do. Let me give you an example...